# Python: testing communication over serial port with just one laptop (macOS)

Tags: python, serial-port, emulation

I'm writing application in ***Python*** which should communicate over serial port (rs232) → send/receive string data (or whole .txt/.csv files) which should be locally stored and compared to another already validated data and with respect to the deviation corrected.

Is there a way how to simulate serial port on macOS (where should I send/receive plaint text or small files)? I haven't find any emulator and I don't think it's possible to do this over terminal while only `/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port` is available.

...so, I can develop the app the home (I don't have another device / laptop available). The measuring device that will communicate with my app is at work and I'm not able to get it home.

Thanks.